# Nginx redirect users to another domain based on Client IP address

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect some users to another website based on their client IP address. For example if user is in range `192.168.0.0/24` they'd be redirected to another website.

I've found [this](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/redirect-nginx-traffic-client-ip/) article which mentions this method:

```
server {
   if ($remote_addr = 1.2.3.4) {   ## Also will it work with subnet address like 192.168.0.0/24?
      rewrite ^ http://www.yourwebsite.com/otherpage.htm;
   }
}
```

I guess it would work fine. But how can I supply IP range list file into this `if` block? Including hundreds of IP address in single line wouldn't look good.

Comment: P.S: I don't have that `geo` module installed nor don't want to break production system. Looks like `geo` module is not installed by default on my nginx.
Edit: I've `--with-http_geoip_module`. Is it that `geo` module everybody talking about?

Comment: Obviously check it on a non-productive-server first...but either the geo module or some intricate regex. It's what the module is for!